# Java String pool object creation

Tags: java, string

I have doubts that whether my concepts are clear in stringpool. Please study the following set of code and check if my answers are correct in number of objects created after the following set of statements:-

1)

```
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = "def";
s2 + "xyz";
```

2)

```
 String s1 = "abc";
 String s2 = "def";
 s2 = s2 + "xyz";
```

3)

```
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = "def";
String s3 = s2 + "xyz";
```

4)

```
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = "def";
s2 + "xyz";
String s3 = "defxyz";
```

As per what i know conceptually, in all the 4 cases above, there will be 4 objects created after the execution of each set of the lines.

Comment: Tell us why, for example, in number 3 why there are 4 objects.

Comment: In the first three there are only 3 string objects each...

Comment: @djna: True. The compiler is free to use only three objects, since s2 + "xyz" can be evaluated at compile-time.

Comment: @John Skeet: Why not in the last one, too?

Comment: @Thilo, In the last one there are 4 distinct literals.  I suppose we are not considering dead code elimination. :)

Comment: In the first three, there are 3 distinct literals, but one more object created by the concatenation. Why does that not make four objects? Or is this only about objects in the String pool (not including runtime Strings)?

Comment: By objects do you mean any object (including eg StringBuilder)? Or just String objects?

Answer (score 8):

You cannot have an expression like `s2 + "xyz"` on its own.  Only constants are evaluated by the compiler and only string constants are automatically added to the String literal pool.

e.g.

```
final String s1 = "abc"; // string literal
String s2 = "abc"; // same string literal

String s3 = s1 + "xyz"; // constants evaluated by the compiler 
                        // and turned into "abcxyz"

String s4 = s2 + "xyz"; // s2 is not a constant and this will
                        // be evaluated at runtime. not in the literal pool.
assert s1 == s2;
assert s3 != s4; // different strings.
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you care? Some of this depends on how aggressively the compiler optimizes so there is no actual correct answer.