# String copying in java

Tags: java, string, copy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java String pool object creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144059/java-string-pool-object-creation)

If i do

```
String one = "hai";
String Two = "hai";
```

is the String Two referring to string one only(same memory location as "hai is stored") or has it created a fresh copy of "hai" somewhere else and pointing to that?

Comment: can you delete this question or accept another answer? i want to delete my answer and system doesn't allow since it is an accepted answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
String one = "hai";
String two = "hai";
```

In Java, Strings are stored in **constant pool** thus even if you assign them as above, they will still refer to the same object.

Comment: Is that anchored in the JLS or just happens to be so?

Comment: @JanDvorak JVM manages String objects in constant pool and if you assign a string a value that is already existing in the pool, your string variable is made referring to the one in the pool by JVM.

Comment: @RohitJain you see that I'm again top on a negative-voted question =)

Comment: The question is edited now.. i wanted to ask this question only.

Comment: @stallion too late dude, you have already got too many downvotes =(

Comment: @ivanovic: so if we have two objects which have same state then they refer(share) to memory location, is it? or is it true only with the immutable objects??

Comment: @ivanovic: that's fine..everyone makes mistakes. this time i have a made a stupid one..:P

Comment: it is true just for objects of type String in java.

Comment: @ivanovic: hmm.. interesting.. wonder why only for strings?

Comment: @stallion Auto-boxed constants are pre-generated and cached for small values of Character, Short, Integer and Long. All Boolean and Byte values are cached.

Answer (score 8):

It is the same instance. You are just creating another reference to same object

Answer (score 2):

String Two just refers to the same object in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Two string variables pointing to the same data in heap memory. So String one and two points to hai in heap memory.

Answer (score 0):

Now Even if you do this

```
one=null;
```

then also "hai" will remain in memory and variable two will refer to that location.
I hope it clears the concept. :)