# String Constant pool object cardianality

Tags: java, string

There is a below mentioned code, I just want to know that how many objects will be created.

```
String s1 = "a";
String s2 = "b";
String s3 = "c";
String s4 = "abc";
```

and if following is the siuation then

```
String s1= "abc"
String s2= "ab"
```

Comment: What do *you* think?

Comment: 4 objects in the first case and 2 in the second. If you are assuming that `"ab"` will be taken out from `"abc"`, then you are wrong.

Comment: Just count them... 4 in the first and 2 in the second. Remember that in Java Strings are immutable!

Comment: It's possible that if `s2` was `"bc"` then some compacting could take place. But I doubt is does as it's such an edge case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java String pool object creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144059/java-string-pool-object-creation)

Answer (score 0):

total 4 objects for the first four strings  and 2 objects for next 2 Strings will be created unless it have the same value as below:

```
String s1 = "ab";
String s2 = "ab";
String s3 = "abc";
```

in the above code it get creates only 2 objects

I hope this will help you

Comment: @santosh dude u did'nt got my question , I just wana know whether operations are being performed inside th epool or not